# how to set automatic tests with smartd for Broadcom / LSI SAS2008 controller

Tags: hard-drive, lsi, smartctl

I have a server that I want to set up automatic tests with smartd for hdd.

From what I see this is my controller

81:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Broadcom / LSI SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)

#ls -al /sys/block/sd* | grep -i '81:00.0'

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  9 06:30 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:0/end_device-0:0:0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  9 06:30 /sys/block/sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:1/end_device-0:0:1/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 14 09:30 /sys/block/sdc -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:2/end_device-0:0:2/target0:0:2/0:0:2:0/block/sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  9 06:30 /sys/block/sdd -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:3/end_device-0:0:3/target0:0:3/0:0:3:0/block/sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  9 06:30 /sys/block/sde -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:4/end_device-0:0:4/target0:0:4/0:0:4:0/block/sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 14 09:30 /sys/block/sdf -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:5/end_device-0:0:5/target0:0:5/0:0:5:0/block/sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  9 06:30 /sys/block/sdg -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:6/end_device-0:0:6/target0:0:6/0:0:6:0/block/sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug  9 06:30 /sys/block/sdh -> ../devices/pci0000:80/0000:80:02.0/0000:81:00.0/host0/port-0:0/expander-0:0/port-0:0:7/end_device-0:0:7/target0:0:7/0:0:7:0/block/sdh

I tried **/dev/sda -a -d megaraid,0 -s (S/../.././02|L/../../6/03) -m x@x.com** but is not showing any test when I check with **smartd -q showtests**

Any info on how to setup automatic tests for this controller?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I forgot to comment DEVICESCAN line and everything that was under it was ignored.